# How to get a list of most similar vertexes given an array of references in gremlin

Tags: gremlin, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

Given a graph like this:

[image]

---

Where A,B,C... are let's say books, and the edges mean 2 books are similar, and the degree of similarity is expressed in the number in the edge. The direction of the edge doesn't matter.

Given N references, I would like to retrieve the most similar immediately connected edges by SUMMING up the connected similarity number, ordered by the most similar first and without duplicates, without including the references.

In the example above, given A and B, we would return

```
F, 50
D, 45
E, 31
C, 30
G, 3
```

Could you provide some help with the query? here is what I thought it should look like, but no luck:

```
g.V('A','B').as('references').bothV().bothE().where(neq('references')).group('id').by('similarity',sum()).order().by('sum_similarity',desc)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the query to do it:

```
g.V().has('name', within(['A','B'])).as('references')
.bothE().as('e').otherV()
.group().by('name').by(select('e').values('similarity').sum())
.unfold().order().by(values, desc)
```

**Explanation:**

The first line selects the reference vertices by 'name' using `within`.

The second line traverses to the immediate neighbors, while keeping reference of the edge.

The third line groups the vertices by 'name' as key and the sum of the referenced edges 'similarity' as value.

The last line disassembles the map using `unfold` and orders it by values in descending order.

Comment: thanks ! order().by(values,desc) didn't work on azure CosmoDB, and I needed to implement the removal of references differently; so my final result that works is:


g.V('A','B').bothE().as('e').otherV().has('id', without('A','B')).group().by('id').by(select('e').values('similarity').sum()).unfold().order().by(values,decr).limit(3)

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer. As for the order by, incr and decr were deprecated in version 4.3.x in favor of asc and desc, which are more standard. Probably CosmosDB is still aligned to the older version.

Answer (score 0):

Kfir's would probably work, but it doesn't take missing `similarity` properties into account (which seems to be possible, given the edge between 'A' and 'B'). Also, you don't need to use any steps that would enable path tracking.

Let's start with your graph:

```
g = TinkerGraph.open().traversal()
g.addV().property(id, 'A').as('A').
  addV().property(id, 'B').as('B').
  addV().property(id, 'C').as('C').
  addV().property(id, 'D').as('D').
  addV().property(id, 'E').as('E').
  addV().property(id, 'F').as('F').
  addV().property(id, 'G').as('G').
  addV().property(id, 'H').as('H').
  addV().property(id, 'J').as('J').
  addE('similarTo').from('A').to('C').property('similarity', 30).
  addE('similarTo').from('D').to('A').property('similarity', 20).
  addE('similarTo').from('E').to('A').property('similarity', 10).
  addE('similarTo').from('B').to('A').
  addE('similarTo').from('B').to('D').property('similarity', 25).
  addE('similarTo').from('B').to('E').property('similarity', 21).
  addE('similarTo').from('F').to('B').property('similarity', 50).
  addE('similarTo').from('G').to('B').property('similarity', 3).
  addE('similarTo').from('F').to('H').property('similarity', 80).
  addE('similarTo').from('H').to('J').property('similarity', 5).
  addE('similarTo').from('J').to('F').property('similarity', 11).iterate()
```

Now, the query that takes missing properties into account, and uses only steps that don't require path-tracking, would be:

```
gremlin> g.V('A','B','C').
         union(outE('similarTo').sack(assign).
                                   by(coalesce(values('similarity'),
                                               constant(0))).inV(),
               inE('similarTo').sack(assign).
                                  by(coalesce(values('similarity'),
                                              constant(0))).outV()).
         hasId(without('A','B', 'C')).
         group().
           by().
           by(sack().sum()).
         order(local).
           by(values, desc).
         limit(local, 3).next()
==>v[F]=50
==>v[D]=45
==>v[E]=31
```

The result is a map containing the 3 most similar vertices and their respective similarity score.

Comment: sorry buddy, I learned a lot from your query, but I missed adding the "similarity" node between A and B by mistake, if they are not similar, there wouldn't be any edges